# Data Transfer from Clients DB to centeral DB Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have DB Oracle in two clients independently with the same structures.
 and I want to transfer data from each client to Central DB Oracle with new PK and FK for each one With the consistency of data in each data base according to sequences in Central DB.

Is there any tools in oracle DB or solution to doing this.

Comment: Have a look at [replication](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76959/repover.htm).

Comment: Since you need to change PK, FK before merging it to Central DB so i don't think you can find any ready made utility with such type of custom requirement. However, if you introduce one more column in PK e.g. Client ID in the table then in this case you would be able to merge data at Central DB without making any changes in PK/FK. Further, you may write your own program by using BulkInsert to update Central DB robustly.

Comment: Thank you Sam, that's what I thought before asking the question